# Entering DataString from Form into table rows

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition 4 and I have this set of tables and columns in my db:

- `javascript_db.sdf` (name of my database)
- `Variables` (name of my table inside `javascript_db.sdf`)
- `ID`, `Name` (columns in `Variables` table)

and I want to add all my strings in my MainForm to the `Name` column, filling `ID` column also counting all `Name`.

Sample:

```
String js[] = { "true", "false", "function", "for" };
```

and output must be (on table `Variables`):

```
ID------Name
1      true
2      false
3      function
4      for
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Also how can I do that in 2set of different strings?

Sample:

```
String js[] = { "true", "false", "function", "for" };
String aa = { "11", "22", "33", "44", "55" };
```

Output:

```
ID------Name------SampleColumn
    1      true        11
    2      false       22
    3      function    33
    4      for         44
```

Comment: You want to use a `ListView`, a `DataGridView` or a `TableLayoutPanel` ? `ListView` seems to be the most appropriate.

Comment: I want DataGridView @BenoitBlanchon if its ok also if its ok  if I can know how can I edit and delete a row/column and refresh and ID number back at the same time if a column deleted if its ok